# Wix Installer issue for small updation

Tags: wix

Currently I am working with .net Wix Installer.I installed it once and after that I made some changes in application. Then again I tried to install with new build, but minor upgrade is not happening here. Version is same in both.But product id is set as "*".
Please help me to find a way in Wix to solve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not hapenning"? Did you specify `<MajorUpgrade AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" .../>` . It is needed if you want have same versions on both installers. But if you want to do real Minor upgrade, you need to increase Version, this way, the installer should make new installation, if I am correct.

Comment: No. I didn't specify AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" in MajorUpgrade. On second build installation is not happening. That's what I meant.